# Sum two columns from temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, field

I'm new to SQL and not sure how to sum two columns from a temp table, any help welcome.

Script is as below:

```
SELECT
    Provider,
    StartYear,
    CAST(YEAR([EndYear]) AS INT) AS 'EndYear'
INTO 
    #a
FROM 
    TABLE1

SELECT
    *, SUM(EndYear - StartYear) AS 'Years'
FROM 
    #a
```

I get the error message:

> a.provider is invalid in the select list because it is not contained
>   in either an aggregate function or GROUP BY clause

Sample Data

```
Provider    StartYear   EndYear 
A1          1940        15/04/2016 00:00 
A2          1930        08/06/2016 00:00 
A3          1932        04/06/2016 00:00 
A2          1932        15/06/2016 00:00 
A1          1944        01/07/2016 00:00
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to provide some sample data

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL server management stuido

Comment: Provider StartYear   EndYear
A1        1940           15/04/2016 00:00
A2        1930           08/06/2016 00:00
A3        1932           04/06/2016 00:00
A2        1932           15/06/2016 00:00
A1        1944           01/07/2016 00:00

Comment: I've copied the sample data from comments to your question, to demonstrate how much easier it is to read.  Can you edit the question, to include expected output?  This gives anyone kind enough to help you something to test against.  It also helps them make sure they've understood what you want.

Comment: @destination-data thanks for doing that - new to the site as well, so just figuring out how to edit my question.... the output I would like like to be exactly the same as the sample data you kindly put into the question, but with one additional column - being the calculation or endyear minus startyear as 'years'

Comment: Not a problem.  It can take a while to find your way around (especially learning to format).  If @GordonLinoff helped you, please consider [accepting his answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  This rewards the contributor and helps others to find a working answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a temporary table.  I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (t1.EndYear - t1.StartYear) as Years
FROM table1 t1;
```

or:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       DATEDIFF(year, t1.StartYear, t1.EndYear) as Years
FROM table1 t1;
```

Edit:  If you actually want to sum the values, just remove the `t1.*` and add `sum()`:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.EndYear - t1.StartYear) as Years
FROM table1 t1;
```

In your case, you should fix the names of your columns.  Something called "Year" should not be a datetime.  But, it is easy enough to convert:

```
SELECT SUM(YEAR(t1.EndYear) - t1.StartYear) as Years
FROM table1 t1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Gordon, my startyear field is an integer and my endyear field is date/time, so i needed to convert the endyear to an integer, only way I could think of doing that was to create a temp table?

Comment: @user5963361 . . . You do not need a temporary table for that.